# Using Horizontal Recyclerview in Listview

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an app for android TV. In my app there is a requirement to display video thumbnail category wise with category name. For fulfill this requirement i used `Listview` for display category wise thumbnail. In a `ListView` each row contains a TextView that display category name and a `Recyclerview` that display thumbnail in horizontal direction. For displaying thumbnail horizontally I used `ImageButton` to manage automatic navigation through DPAD controller.it all working fine when i pressed DPAD UP and DOWN key it navigate from one category to another category video thumbnail and when I pressed left and right DPAD key it navigate from one thumbnail to another thumbnail on same category. But problem is that it only navigate on visible thumbnail. After selecting last thumbnail when we pressed DPAD RIGHT key then horizontal `Recyclerview` does not scroll to display next thumbnail. It only navigate Right or Left only on visible item and my requirement is it should navigate all thumbnail of particular category. Please help me.......

below is my activity code that contains Listview

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen_layout);

        verticalListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.category_listview);
        verticalListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        verticalListView.setDividerHeight(30);
        HomeCategoryListAdapter adapter = new HomeCategoryListAdapter(this,categoriesVideoList,categoryDataList);
        verticalListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

below is my ListAdapter class

```
public class HomeCategoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity context;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<VideoContentModel>> categoriesVideoList;
    private ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryDataList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public HomeCategoryListAdapter(Activity context,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<VideoContentModel>> categoriesVideoList,
            ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryDataList) {

        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.categoriesVideoList = categoriesVideoList;
        this.categoryDataList = categoryDataList;
        inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }

    public int getCount() {

        return categoryDataList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_name_vertical_row, null);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)vi.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_recyclerview);
            TextView cateTitleName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.cat_title_name);    

            cateTitleName.setText(categoryDataList.get(position).getCatTitle());
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            CategoryContentThumbnailAdapter adapter = new CategoryContentThumbnailAdapter(context,categoriesVideoList.get(position),
                    categoryDataList.get(position).getCatDfpTag());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);   

    return vi;
}
}
```

below is Recyclerview adapter class

```
public class CategoryContentThumbnailAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryContentThumbnailAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
Activity context;
int focusedItem = 0;
ArrayList<VideoContentModel> catVideoList;
String dfpTag;

public CategoryContentThumbnailAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<VideoContentModel> catVideoList, String dfpTag) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.catVideoList = catVideoList;
    this.dfpTag = dfpTag;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cat_row_thumbnail, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    VideoContentModel model = catVideoList.get(position);
    try {
        new com.calkins.imageloder.ImageLoader(context, 156, 1).DisplayImage(model.getVideoThumbnailUrl(),older.imageButton);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return catVideoList.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageButton imageButton;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.cat_button_thumabnail);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: check this http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html if it helps

Comment: @Raghunandan actually i need control through DPAD. My program will work with screen touch but no working through DPAD controller.